# Positioning child content outside of parent container

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I'm trying to visually position a DIV (article header) outside of it's parent DIV (article) container. Is this possible?

[image]

My mark-up example is available here - http://codepen.io/calebo/pen/CGoyD

Comment: Is it possible to edit the markup, if needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.main {
  background: tomato;
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 30px;        /* above Layout adjustment */
  /* removed overflow: hidden; */
  /* use always clearfix method instead */
}
.article_header {
  background: SteelBlue;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;  /* to neutralize padding of parent container */
  left: -10px;          /* to neutralize padding of parent container */
  padding: 10px;        /* to neutralize padding of parent container */
  right: -330px;        /* to neutralize padding of parent container */
}
.main > article{
  position: relative;
}
.aside {
  background: cyan;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 30px;        /* above Layout adjustment */
}
```

**[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wtvdI)**

To make adjustments, play with margin property.

Comment: If you would only change `.article_header` width to a fixed `px` unit,  like 920px, this works. Also, I think you need to set `left: 0; right: 0` for older versions of IE.

Comment: Hey, you don't need to mess with `.article_header` margins. You already got it the first time, and only a fixed width was needed. Here's [a CodePen with your original answer fixed](http://codepen.io/carlesjove/pen/Fxjlc)

Comment: @CarlesJoveBuxeda ohh I was assuming only aside width is fixed. but still I think there is no much difference in our way of coding. you mentioned the `width: 920px;` and I mentioned `right: 330px;` which is combination of aside element width, side paddings and neutralizing of `left: -10px;`. BTW, you wrote `margin-left: -10px;` and `left: 10px` which can be shortened to just `left: -10px;` :)

Comment: The *Working Fiddle* link should be *Working CodePen*, it's not fiddle :)

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes, after all it's the same effect. I just find the other way cleaner, since he's already setting a fixed with for the container `.inner-wrap`. Let him choose ;-)

Comment: @KingKing just got used to it :)

Comment: If I had more content in the header or content before the 'inner-wrap' div. the header seems to sit on top of it. See example: codepen.io/calebo/pen/uibwz

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this can be done

```
<div class="wrapper">        
<h2>Desired effect</h2>

    <div class="inner-wrap">
        <div class="main">
            <article>
                <header class="article_header">article header - unknown height</header>
                <section class="article_body">article body</section>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="aside">aside</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:80%;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.inner-wrap {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;
    margin: 41px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 940px;
}
.inner-wrap > * {
    padding: 10px;
}
.main {
    background: tomato;
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
}
.article_header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #4682B4;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -39px;
    width: 98%;
}
.aside {
    background: cyan;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w26yw/1/** i.e: http://jsfiddle.net/w26yw/1/show/

Comment: This is not what he's asking for... Plus is alters the markup. A `header` outside an `article` tag is not semantically correct...

Comment: @CarlesJoveBuxeda If I add more content to the header, it covers up the body content beneath it, the header must be of flexible height.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
.inner-wrap {position: relative; overflow: visible;}

.inner-wrap:after {content:""; display:table; clear:both;}

.article_header {position: absolute; width: 940px; left: 0; bottom: 100%;}
```

I've removed the `overflow: hidden` and replaced it with a `clearfix` method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the cleanest solution. It is basically the original @Mr_Green answer with a little fix.

```
.main > article {
  position: relative;
}
.article_header {
  background: SteelBlue;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;  /* to neutralize padding of parent container */
  margin-left: -10px;   /* to neutralize padding of parent container */
  padding: 0px 10px;    /* to neutralize padding of parent container */
  width: 920px;
}
.inner-wrap {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* remove overflow: hidden */
}
```

Here's a [working CodePen](http://codepen.io/carlesjove/pen/Fxjlc)

Comment: +1 just a comment (_as I already mentioned in other comment_), margin-left and left can be shortened to just `left: -10px;`

Comment: @Mr_Green `left: 0` and `right: 0` is for older versions of IE. It's like saying "make sure this takes all the container width". However, since there's a fixed width I'm not sure if it'd be necessary...

Comment: If I had more content in the header or content before the 'inner-wrap' div. the header seems to sit on top of it. See example: http://codepen.io/calebo/pen/uibwz