# Float image outside of parent container

Tags: css, image, css-position

Firstly, I know this may seem like a duplicate of [Positioning child content outside of parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705723/positioning-child-content-outside-of-parent-container), but this is slightly different.

I've only had success floating an image outside of its parent container if I use an absolutely positioned div with the `background-image` set. Example of code used to achieve this:

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 140px;
}
```

Now I need to achieve the same with an `<img />` element. What I'm hoping to achieve is something like this:

[image]

So the image should actually spill over on the left and right of the parent container. I've tried similar methids as given above, but without success. Any advice?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is z-index on the child image, which will make sure it's on the top of the parent, regardless of how it's positioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this?

```css
.parent {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:lightgray;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.child {
    width: 200px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 100px;;
    background-color:gray;
    position:abolute; 
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <img class='child'/>
</div>
```

edit: as per the comments below this is what i see[image]

Comment: I don't know why this didn't work on my local site using the same code as in my example, but I just tried this in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4tp0ar1r/

Comment: @maGz for your js fiddle, what is your desired result? (since the image is smaller than the parent container)

Comment: Sorry, I think the "main" div (acting as the body) confused things. I've updated it (http://jsfiddle.net/4tp0ar1r/2/) and removed the `.main` div. The Parent box is now visible, and you will see the image larger. Its just a random image I picked.

Comment: @maGz im sorry, i possibly dont see what you're seeing. yoda's width is smaller than the gray div behind it, so i'm lost as to what your desired result is?

Comment: huh? I'm using Chrome on Mac, and I can see Yoda in front, larger than the grey box. Could you possibly send a screenshot?

Comment: @maGz i added a screenshot of what i see from your code

Comment: WOAH! that's totally different to how I see it! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51197907/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-28.png
wonder why? maybe I need to specify `width` and `height` in CSS

Comment: @maGz yours looks better lol, anyways, just adjust the margin-top and margin-left to whatever you want to center the image however you'd like it to

Answer (score 1):

See the method bellow

1. Wrap the image in a DIV
2. Add border-radius to achieve the egg like shape
3. Add overflow with a value of hidden to the image container
4. use an image that's bigger than it's container so that it will take on the egg like shape.

```css
#square {
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #6D9BBE;
  position: relative; /* Relative to curtail overlap */
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  
  }

#square #eggy {
  
  width: 380px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #8500B2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

#eggy img {
  width: 390px
    height: 240px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="square">

<div id="eggy"><img src="http://s9.postimg.org/xnmcpb0jz/use_this.png"/></div><!-- End Eggy -->


</div><!-- End Square -->
```